# Customizing native web components styling by the consumer

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

I've got a bunch of web components built where a consumer may be consuming one or many of these components.

They are used by adding a `script` tag to the components minified JS and then using the web component in your code like so: `<my-cool-component data="someData" />`.

CSS is built into these components, however, I need to add functionality to allow the consumers to customize the color theme, and I'm wondering if my approach here could be improved, or **if there is a better approach** all together.

Right now I have it setup so that when someone consumes any of the components, like `my-cool-component` and they have a `window.coolComponentOptions` set like this:

```
window.coolComponentOptions = {
  PRIMARY_BUTTON_BACKGROUND_COLOR: 'tomato',
  PRIMARY_BUTTON_COLOR: '#fff',
  URL_COLOR: 'tomato',
  FONT: 'Arial',
  SECONDARY_BUTTON_BACKGROUND_COLOR: 'lightblue',
  ... // Obviously this could grow tremendously
}
```

I do a check inside of `my-cool-component` and see if the `coolComponentOptions` exist and if so I map them to the CSS variables and use them inside of any of the components.

Alternatively I could make these values props on the component itself like `<my-cool-component primary-btn-color="tomato" />` but this could cause the consumer to have an element with tons of attributes, and when they consume `<other-cool-comp />` they will need to repeat these attributes again.

I'm curious if there are any other (better) options than the way I am doing it with the `window` variable, or if that approach could be improved upon or is completely acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS variables**  can be global CSS definitions.

And **shadowParts** give you even more global CSS **/** shadowDOM styling.

Very good explainer by Monica Dinculescu, former Google Web Components team member

**https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/**

[image]